# Android Studio, making a selection turns on the insert key

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This problem happen just this morning, whenever I make a selection on android studio, the insert cursor activate.

[image: selection activating the insert key image]

What I've tried:
To press insert, ctrl + insert, fn + insert. It still does the same.

Updated from 3.5.x to 3.6.1. problem still persist.

Using a keyboard tester I don't see any bugging keys.

The problem does not happen on any other software, Intellij IDEA is fine, notepad is fine, etc

I've seen in another thread that disabling the "use block caret" option should help but it didn't

[image: option image]

At this point I'm completely lost in this issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out, I accidently installed the ideavim plugin, I though i uninstalled it before, I guess not.

Answer (score 9):

1. SDK Manager >> Plugins >> Installed
2. You need to disable **IdeaVim** plugin.
3. **Restart** Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

SDK Manager >> Plugins >> Installed
You need to disable IdeaVim plugin.
Restart Android Studio.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSXCi41eNKk

Comment: 1. SDK Manager >> Plugins >> Installed

2. You need to disable IdeaVim plugin.

3. Restart Android Studio.

 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSXCi41eNKk